# Turning lists into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know this question has been asked a million times, but I was having a hard time figuring out a soultion for my problem.

this is my code:

```
try:
    dict1={}
    main_list = [line.rstrip() for line in open("food01.csv")]
    print(main_list)
except IOError:
    print("Error opening file")
```

The output for the file(the CSV):

```
['lion,gazelle', 'jackal,grass,zebra,gazelle', 'gazelle,grass,acacia leaves', 'zebra,grass']
```

What I want is dictionary of lists like this:

```
{'lion':['gazelle'],'jackal':['grass,zebra,gazelle'],'gazelle':['grass,acacia leaves'],'zebra':['grass']}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested dict comprehension like this:

```
{first: rest for cols in rows for first, *rest in (cols.split(','),)}
```

so that given:

```
rows = ['lion,gazelle', 'jackal,grass,zebra,gazelle', 'gazelle,grass,acacia leaves', 'zebra,grass']
```

this returns:

```
{'lion': ['gazelle'], 'jackal': ['grass', 'zebra', 'gazelle'], 'gazelle': ['grass', 'acacia leaves'], 'zebra': ['grass']}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you use slightly more descriptive variable names in stuff like this; makes it much more readable.

Comment: I am a new contributor to SO, and I sometime feel using too much list comprehension sometimes makes the code harder to read, like in this case

Comment: As OP I had the same problem, but after reading it over a few times I figured it out and just replaced the variable names that I understood better and worked with my code. A very good solution, thank you blhsing!

Comment: Sure, renamed the variables for clarity then.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
lst = ['lion,gazelle', 'jackal,grass,zebra,gazelle', 'gazelle,grass,acacia leaves', 'zebra,grass']

dct = {}
for l in lst:
    items = l.split(',')
    dct[items[0]] = items[1:]

print(dct)
#{'lion': ['gazelle'], 'jackal': ['grass', 'zebra', 'gazelle'], 'gazelle': ['grass', 'acacia leaves'], 'zebra': ['grass']}
```

Comment: Note that this will not append anything to the dict if there's a single word in that line. If you want the element to be there with an empty list as value you can drop the `if`

Answer (score 0):

You need to have 2 lists for this. 1 for keys 1 for values
Try to split the predators and preys into 2 lists and then use zip to combine them in a dictionary

```
keys = ["lion", "jackal", 'gazelle']
values = [["gazelle"], ["grass, zebra, gazelle"], ["grass, acacia leaves"]]
dict1 = dict(zip(keys, values))
print(dict1)
```